# C: Is using char faster than using int?

Tags: c, performance, types, char, integer

Since char is only 1 byte long, is it better to to use char while dealing with 8-bit unsigned int?

Example:
I was trying to create a struct for storing rgb values of a color.

```
struct color
{
  unsigned int r: 8;
  unsigned int g: 8;
  unsigned int b: 8;
};
```

Now since it is int, it allocates a memory of 4 bytes in my case. But if I replace them with unsigned char, they will be taking 3 bytes of memory as intended (in my platform).

Comment: Efficiency for what, size or performance? CPU could event work slower with data less than native size. You can use `uint_fast8_t` to get best fit for performance.

Comment: @dimich Can you say what is the difference between  unsigned char and uint_fast8_t? For example what will be returned for both types by the operator sizeof?

Comment: What is you use case of conversion? You might want to add a [mre].

Comment: @VladfromMoscow on what architecture? On x86 they are the same 1 byte, CPU can work with bytes separately.

Comment: @dimich And where are these types different?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow E.g. on ARMv7 it is 4 bytes.

Comment: @dimich What is equal to 4 bytes?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow `sizeof(uint_fast8_t)` is equal to 4 bytes.

Comment: @dimich: ARMv7 is an architecture, not a C implementation. `sizeof (uint_fast8_t)` is not 4 in all C implementations for that architecture.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Sure. It is for gcc. I gave an example where `sizeof(char)` can be not equal to `sizeof(uint_fast8_t)`

Comment: @dimich: GCC is a compiler, not a C implementation. It forms part of a C implementation, when combined with a choice of architecture and other settings, a standard library implementation, platform headers, and possibly other parts. GCC interacts with the platform headers to configure the implementation, and I think that includes setting the type (and hence the size) for `uint_fast8_t`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil `uint_fast8_t` is defined in C99 standard.

Comment: @dimich: No, it is not. Its characteristics are partially specified in the C standard, but the actual definition is left up to the C implementation. When it is defined, it is a `typedef` name, and typically it is defined to be an alias for a standard integer type, although an implementation could choose to make it an alias for an extended integer type. E.g., in Apple’s Xcode, the specific definition of `uint_fast8_t` arises not from anything built into GCC but from a header file that is part of the platform SDK that defines it to be `unsigned char` (for macOS 10.15).

Comment: @EricPostpischil Of course it is implementation-defined. `int`, `long` etc are also implementation-defined. What is your objection? Are you stating they are always equal? I gave an example when size of `uint_fast8_t` can be not equal to size of char. Why? Because target CPU have no instructions to work with chars separately and casting to char requires additional instructions. That's the reason why this kind of types are instroduced.

Comment: @dimich: The problem is you have not given an example yet. You said `uint_fast8_t` is four bytes in ARMv7, but I do not know of a C implementation for ARMv7 in which `uint_fast8_t` is four bytes. You have not identified any such implementation. I am sitting in front of a C implementation for ARMv7, and `uint_fast8_t` is one byte in it. If you want to give an example, you need to identify the specific C implementation, with enough details about vendor, version, compiler, or whatever else is needed to narrow it down to something other people can check.

Comment: @EricPostpischil `arm-none-eabi-gcc (Arch Repository) 12.1.0` Compilation flags: `-O2 -march=armv7`. I don't see a sense in pointless arguing. Have a nice day!

Comment: Using a bit-field with 8 bits instead of an `unsigned char` is not an int-char _conversion_. It is a usage of another type. The size of the resulting structure is implementation-defined.

Comment: @saxbophone I actually wasn't aware that it wasn't a conversion case... I just wanted to know if it would be inefficient to use char in terms of speed.

Comment: No problem, hope it helps

Answer (score 6):

No. Maybe a tiny bit.

First, this is a very platform dependent question.
However the `<stdint.h>` header was introduced to help with this.

Some hardware platforms are optimised for a particular size of operand and have an overhead to using smaller (in bit-size) operands even though logically the smaller operand requires less computation.

You should find that `uint_fast8_t` is the fastest unsigned integer type with at least 8 bits (`#include <stdint.h>` to use it).
That may be the same as `unsigned char` or `unsigned int` depending on whether your question is 'yes' or 'no' respectively(*).

So the idea would be that if you're speed focused you'd use `uint_fast8_t` and the compiler will pick the fastest type fitting your purpose.

There are a couple of downsides to this scheme.
One is that if you create very vast quantities of data performance can be impaired (and limits reached) because you're using an 'oversized' type for the purpose.

On a platform where a 4-byte `int` is faster than a 1-byte `char` you're using about 4 times as much memory as you need.
If your platform is small or your scale large that can be a significant overhead.

Also you need to be careful that if the underlying type isn't the minimum size you expect then some calculations may be confounded.

Arithmetic 'clocks' neatly for unsigned operands but obviously at different sizes if `uint_fast8_t` isn't in fact 8-bits.

It's platform dependent what the following returns:

```
#include <stdint.h>

//...

int foo() {
   uint_fast8_t x=255; 
   ++x;
   if(x==0){
       return 1;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

The overhead of dealing with potentially outsized types can claw back your gains.

I tend to agree with Knuth that "premature optimisation is the root of all evil" and would say you should only get into this sort of cleverness if you need it.

Do a typedef for `typedef uint8_t color_comp;` for now and get the application working before trying to shave off fractions of a second performance later!

I don't know what your application does but it may be that it's not compute intensive in RGB channels and the bottleneck (if any) is elsewhere. Maybe you find some high load calculation where it's worth dealing with `uint_fast8_t` conversions and issues.

The wisdom of Knuth is that you probably don't know where that is until later anyway.

(*) It could be `unsigned long` or indeed some other type. The only constraint is that it is an unsigned type and at least 8 bits.

Comment: You raise a really good point about the pitfalls of `uint_fastN_t` and `uint_leastN_t` —if one relies upon wraparound arithmetic on unsigned overflow (such as an 8-bit counter), an exact-width type like `uint8_t` should probably be used, regardless of the potential for inefficiency on some platforms.

Comment: @saxbophone The whole C model of generally specifying minimums and not actual limits can lead to issues. In many industries including the motor industry you're required to work with explicit sizes because they're safer than they are clever!